# SQL multiple Select on same column

Tags: mysql

As in the image below I am selecting posts based on an OR. I would like to change this to an AND but when I do that I get no records returning. Can anyone help?

Thanks

[image]

Comment: I don't understand what's wrong about using OR. You will never have any dataset that has a column that is equal to two opposing values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want something like this:

```
SELECT p.post_title,
       r.object_id
FROM wp_term_relatiosnhips AS r
LEFT OUTER JOIN wp_posts AS p ON p.ID = r.object_id
WHERE r.term_taxonomy_id IN (6, 10)
GROUP BY p.post_title,
         r.object_id 
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT CASE 
                         WHEN r.term_taxonomy_id IN (6, 10) 
                         THEN r.term_taxonomy_id 
                      END) = 2
```

The above query will return `p.post_title, r.object_id` pairs being related to *both* `6, 10` `term_taxonomy_id` values, i.e. `Buy Annual Leave, 2789` based on your sample data.

Comment: Yes this is what I was looking for, thank you. I'm going to study this now.

Answer (score 0):

if you don't want use or you can use AND IN clause

```
select 
  wp_posts.post:title,
  wp_term_relationships.object_id,
  wp_ter_relationships.term_taxonomy_id
from wp_term_relationships
  left outer join wp_posts
     on (wp_term_relationships.object_id = wp_posts.ID 
           and wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy in (6,10));
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you want to retrieve records from wp_posts with more than one matching row in wp_term_relationships.

I'm struggling a bit to imagine what the prupose of the left join is in the query you've provided. I'll assume that there isn't some hidden and very obscure logic to its function.

Consider:

```
SELECT *
FROM wp_posts AS wpp
INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships AS wtr1
   ON wpp.id=wtr1.object_id
INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships AS wtr2
   ON wpp.id=wtr2.object_id
WHERE wtr1.term_taxonomy_id=6
AND wtr2.term_taxonomy_id=10;
```

(or use the method described by Giorgos)